# C++ boost multi_index_container modify on get_nth<1>

Tags: c++, boost

I can call `modify` on a `boost::multi_index_container` via an iterator obtained from `get<0>().find()`. However, when I try to do the same on `get<1>().find()`, I get a compilation error.

Is it possible to modify via an iterator on the second index?

I am using `g++4.9.2`  and `boost 1.55`.

The code is

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>

using std::string;
using boost::multi_index::indexed_by;
using boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique;
using boost::multi_index::member;

struct Person
{
    string FamilyName;
    string PersonalName;
    //        string MiddleName;
};

typedef boost::multi_index_container
<
    Person,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_non_unique<member<Person, string, &Person::FamilyName>>,
        ordered_non_unique<member<Person, string, &Person::PersonalName>>
    >
>
PersonList;

main()
{
    PersonList people;

    {
        string toFind = "Jones";
        string toReplace = "Smith";

        PersonList::nth_index<0>::type::const_iterator itr0( people.get<0>().find(toFind) );
        const PersonList::nth_index<0>::type::const_iterator end0(people.get<0>().cend());

        for( ; itr0!= end0; itr0++)
        {
            people.modify(itr0, [&](Person &e){ e.FamilyName = toReplace; });
        }

    }

    {
        string toFind = "Fred";
        string toReplace = "Barney";

        PersonList::nth_index<1>::type::const_iterator itr1( people.get<1>().find(toFind) );
        const PersonList::nth_index<1>::type::const_iterator end1(people.get<1>().cend());

        for( ; itr1!= end1; itr1++)
        {
            people.modify(itr1, [&](Person &e){ e.PersonalName = toReplace; });
        }
    }    
}
```

and the errors are

```
LANG=C g++ -std=c++11 boost-test.cpp

boost-test.cpp: In function 'int main()':

boost-test.cpp:57:82: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > > >::modify(boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>::const_iterator&, main()::<lambda(Person&)>)'

                 people.modify(itr1, [&](Person &e){ e.PersonalName = toReplace; });

boost-test.cpp:57:82: note: candidates are:

In file included from boost-test.cpp:4:0:

/usr/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:413:8: note: template<class Modifier> bool boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<KeyFromValue, Compare, SuperMeta, TagList, Category>::modify(boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<KeyFromValue, Compare, SuperMeta, TagList, Category>::iterator, Modifier) [with Modifier = Modifier; KeyFromValue = boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName>; Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; SuperMeta = boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >; TagList = boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>; Category = boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag]

   bool modify(iterator position,Modifier mod)

        ^

/usr/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:413:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

boost-test.cpp:57:82: note:   cannot convert 'itr1' (type 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>::const_iterator {aka boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Person, std::allocator<Person> > > >}') to type 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>::iterator {aka boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Person, std::allocator<Person> > > > >}'

                 people.modify(itr1, [&](Person &e){ e.PersonalName = toReplace; });

                                                                                  ^

In file included from boost-test.cpp:4:0:

/usr/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:434:8: note: template<class Modifier, class Rollback> bool boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<KeyFromValue, Compare, SuperMeta, TagList, Category>::modify(boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<KeyFromValue, Compare, SuperMeta, TagList, Category>::iterator, Modifier, Rollback) [with Modifier = Modifier; Rollback = Rollback; KeyFromValue = boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName>; Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; SuperMeta = boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >; TagList = boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>; Category = boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag]

   bool modify(iterator position,Modifier mod,Rollback back)

        ^

/usr/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:434:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

boost-test.cpp:57:82: note:   cannot convert 'itr1' (type 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>::const_iterator {aka boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Person, std::allocator<Person> > > >}') to type 'boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName>, std::less<std::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, Person, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::FamilyName> >, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::member<Person, std::basic_string<char>, &Person::PersonalName> > >, std::allocator<Person> >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>::iterator {aka boost::multi_index::detail::bidir_node_iterator<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Person, std::allocator<Person> > > > >}'

                 people.modify(itr1, [&](Person &e){ e.PersonalName = toReplace; });

                                                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
people.modify(itr1, [&](Person &e){ e.PersonalName = toReplace; });
```

with

```
people.get<1>().modify(itr1, [&](Person &e){ e.PersonalName = toReplace; });
```

Comment: Thanks. It's obvious when it's pointed out. I'll wait a few days for any other answers before accepting.

Comment: @CSM You can accept this answer. There's no better thing. There's only alternatives that are less efficient in this case: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#projection